# Is there any cache settings in OSM?

Tags: angular, caching, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using OSM to draw country boundries from an json file, downloaded from wambanchers-osm.website, It is working well But this process it taking time to load json file data on Map. is there a way to enable caching or split json file, so that don't have to wait untill complete data is loaded.

```
const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: '../assets/data/countires.json',
        format: new GeoJSON()
      }),
      style: function(feature) {
       style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
        return style;
      }
    });
​
    const raster = new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      })
    }); 

  this.map = new Map({
      layers: [raster, vectorLayer],
      target: 'map',
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([-180.2313499, 39.7232819]),
        zoom: 2,
        constrainOnlyCenter: true
      }),
      interactions: []
    });​
```